# Azure function trigger go to error when start

Tags: azure

I'm trying to implement the example of 'Image Resizer' that I find here:
https://github.com/jefking/fl-image-resize
when I start the function it returns me this error

Exception while executing function: Functions.ImageTriggerCSharp01. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myBlob'. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

subsequently the function is activated every minute without errors. Then, when I load a file, this error is generated:

Function compilation error

error: Missing a trigger argument named 'myBlob'.
warning: Missing binding argument named 'outputBlob'. Mismatched binding argument names may lead to function indexing errors.

what's wrong?

*********UPGRADE***********
i have this code:
run.csx=

```
#r "System.Drawing"

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using ImageProcessor;

private static readonly Size size = new Size(EnvAsInt("ImageResize-Width"), EnvAsInt("ImageResize-Height"));

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, Stream outputBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    if (myBlob==null){
        log.Info($"C# myBlob is NULL");
    }
    log.Info($"C# ok2");
    if (outputBlob==null){
        log.Info($"C# outputBlob is NULL");
    }
    log.Info($"C# ok3");
    using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
    {
        log.Info($"C# ok31");

        imageFactory
            .Load(myBlob)
            .Resize(size)
            .Save(outputBlob);
    }
    log.Info($"C# ok4");
}


private static int EnvAsInt(string name) => int.Parse(Env(name));
private static string Env(string name) => System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
enter code here
```

function.json=

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "photosthumbnails/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "name": "myBlob",
      "path": "photos/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

i have the error in

```
imageFactory
            .Load(myBlob)
            .Resize(size)
            .Save(outputBlob);
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. i resolve.
the error is on

```
private static readonly Size size = new Size(EnvAsInt("ImageResize-Width"), EnvAsInt("ImageResize-Height"));
```

the two properties, ImageResize-Width and ImageResize-Height, were not included in the 'function' settings.

It's my first Azure function ... ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Do verify the parameter names in run.csx and in the function.json file. The parameter names passed in the run.csx file should match with function.json file. Do check them in the reference you provided.

Comment: ok.I'm in confusion. now i have thi error: 2018-10-09T17:33:15.361 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.ImageTriggerCSharp01. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. f-ImageTriggerCSharp01__-248614518: The type initializer for 'Submission#0' threw an exception. mscorlib: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String.
2018-10-09T17:33:15.376 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=384dc66b-6e9b-4c54-acd3-b3073654ac57, Duration=1523ms)